# WooCommerce conditional meta query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta, meta-query

For this question, I know how to solve it but I am hoping there is a better / faster way to solve it.

I have a custom meta query in my product loop that doesn't display my product if the stock is 0, but I only want to do this when backorder is set to no on a product. Is this possible without running 2 queries (one that gets all the posts and checks if backorders are enabled, and one that only executes the meta query if backorders are not enabled)?

Here is my custom meta query in my `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woo_custom_outofstock_query' );

function woo_custom_outofstock_query( $q ) {
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => '_stock',
        'value'     => '0.000000',
        'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the query to:

```
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => '_stock',
    'value'     => '0.000000',
    'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
);

$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => '_backorders',
    'value'     => 'no',
    'compare'   => '!='
);

$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

This should do the trick but for some reason it is still not working.
Also, when I hide out of stock products in the WooCommerce settings, it still doesn't display products with a stock of 0 when backorders are enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default relation for a meta query is `AND`, so when you have two conditions they will be treated as such:

```
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => '_stock',
    'value'     => '0.000000',
    'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
);

$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => '_backorders',
    'value'     => 'no',
    'compare'   => '!='
);
```

Get all products with a `_stock` meta value **NOT IN** `0.000000` **AND** `_backorders` **NOT EQUAL TO** `no`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Exactly what I'm [talking about](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4140/31545) ;-). This question deserves an answer

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this already but it still wouldn't display the product if backorders was yes and the stock is 0.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I agree you could also just see this as a question about meta_queries so that wouldn't make it off topic.

Comment: Have you checked the **Out Of Stock Visibility** checkbox in `Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory` ? That will prevent out of stock products showing.

Comment: Wow this solved it indeed, I thought that this only worked when a product is set to Sold out, It seems i was thinking way too complicated for an uncomplicated situation. Thanks! @userabuser

Comment: @userabuser Although after testing some more it stopped working after I added a new product. I now have two products in one category one is out of stock and one has 1 in stock and the page keeps displaying both products. when I set the second product back to concept it works again.

Comment: You have two products, one is in stock (invetory of 1) and the other is out of stock (inventory of 0). What is the **backorder** status of both products? Because if both products have a backorder status that is anything other than `no` then both of the products will show in the loop.

Comment: Hi I have talked with the developer who originally worked on the site in question and the problem was that it was a custom query in some pages... nevertheless thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted...